# Can I migrate from DTS to an equivalent MySQL tool?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, pentaho, dts, kettle

The work i need to do is to migrate MSSQL 2000 DTS to MySQL, unfortunetly i have not found an equivalent to DTS in MySQL. I thought of using an ETL which is Pentaho Spoon. Therefore i would like to know if it possible to import MSSQL 2000 dts into Pentaho Spoon easily ?
I did not find any answers to my question on google or on the Internet in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do this automatically. However, Kettle is a fairly intuitive tool to use and you should be able to easily migrate DTS to Kettle manually.

That said, a DTS to Kettle conversion tool might be an opportunity for a new product in the market.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, you are totally right ! I am using Kettle to translate those DTS into the ETL language. It is true that no automatic DTS to Kettle conversion exists and it would be a true succes to do so. 
Thanks again for your help and  have a great day